# Differential Equations and Eigenvalues

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, determinant

I have the following system of differential equations:

$$\left\{\begin{aligned} \frac {dx} {dt}=-4x+2y \\  \frac {dy} {dt}=-\frac 5 2x+2y  \end{aligned} \right. $$

Which corresponds to the following augmented matrix (to solve for eigenvectors)

$$ \begin{pmatrix} 
-4 & 2 \\    
-\frac 5 2 & 2\\
\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} 
x \\    
y\\
\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 
0 \\    
0\\
\end{pmatrix} 
$$

The first thing I did was to get rid of the fraction by multiplying the second row by 2.

$$ \begin{pmatrix} 
-4 & 2 \\    
-5 & 4\\
\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} 
x \\    
y\\
\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 
0 \\    
0\\
\end{pmatrix} 
$$

To find the eigenvectors, I start by getting the determinant of the following matrix :

$$ det\begin{pmatrix} 
-4-\lambda & 2 \\    
-5 & 4-\lambda\\
\end{pmatrix} 
$$

Which leads to this: $\lambda^2 -6$. But this of course is not correct!
The solution says that I'm suppose to end up with $\lambda^2 +2\lambda-3$, giving me eigenvalues $\lambda_1=1, \lambda_2=-3$. The only way to end up with a polynomial like that is to NOT multiply the second row by two. So how do I go about doing something like this? Am I missing something here?

Comment: Elementary operations do not preserve eigenvalues. You cannot multiply the second row by $2$.

Comment: Also, multiplying by 2 would also multiply the $dy/dt$. More to the point, the trace of the original matrix is $-2$ and the determinant is $-3$ which matches the sum and product of your given e-value answer. A good thing.

Comment: Your equation is a bit strange, because the system as stated is not coupled. Is there a typo? Otherwise, just solve for $y(t)$.

Comment: @NickThompson yes, there is a typo in my DEs. I'll correct.

Comment: @GitGud So in other words, always leave the augmented matrix in the exact form of its corresponding system of DEs?

Comment: What augmented matrix? Just get the $\lambda$'s in from the get go. The fraction will disappear very quickly anyway because of the multiplication by second entry in the first line (which is $2$).

Comment: @GitGud meant coefficient matrix. Thanks for the help, much appreciated!